# Sequelize: updating updatedAt manually

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Below is the code I am using in Hooks to update the `updatedAt` column for two objects:

```
hooks: {
                afterUpdate: (group, options, callback) => {
                    console.log("groudId " + groupId + " options " + options)
                },
                afterCreate: (member, options, callback) => {
                    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        sequelize.models.Group.findOne({
                            where: {
                                id: member.group_id
                            }
                        }).then((group) => {
                            if (group) {
                                var date = new Date();
                                console.log("BEFORE group.updatedAt " + group.updatedAt)
                                group.dataValues.updatedAt = new Date()
                                console.log("CHANGED group.updatedAt " + group.updatedAt)
                                group.save().then((Group) => {
                                    if (Group) {
                                        console.log("UPDATED Group.updatedAt " + Group.updatedAt)
                                        console.log("UPDATED group.updatedAt " + group.updatedAt)
                                        resolve(Group)
                                    } else {
                                        console.log("NO GROUP Found")
                                        return reject(group.id)
                                    }
                                }).catch((error) => {
                                    return (error)
                                })
                            } else {
                                return reject(id)
                            }
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            return (reject)
                        })
                    })
                }
```

Console Log:

```
BEFORE group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
CHANGED group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:17 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED Group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:17 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:17 GMT-0800 (PST)
BEFORE group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
CHANGED group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:19 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED Group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:19 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED group.updatedAt Tue Feb 28 2017 14:00:19 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

While the log, what I think, appears correct, why isn't the actual object in the DB updated to the new `updatedAt` value?  Or is there an **easier** way to update an objects `updatedAt` column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This worked for me

```
group.changed('updatedAt', true)

await group.update({
    updatedAt: new Date()
})
```

Calling just update with updatedAt = new Date is not enough, you must flag column as changed

Comment: if you don't want to use the "new Date()" (afraid of db <> api TZ, etc) then you can also just use `1` instead of "new Date()" e.g. this `group.changed('updatedAt', true); await group.update({ updatedAt: 1 })`

The value will be overridden anyway so it's just important to include "a value" for it.

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for:

```
group.changed('updatedAt', true)
```

This will mark the `updatedAt` column as dirty so it will be updated.

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me, so I had to use model method instead:

```
await MyModel.update({ updatedAt }, { where: { id: instance.id }, silent: true });
```

Comment: Did you do anything else to get this to work?  Any time I do this, it won't update unless I include some other field in addition to `updatedAt`.

Comment: Ditto, looks like this alone does not work.

Comment: v6 sequelize appears to work the same way. Must add an additional field in order for to actually set `updatedAt`. Interestingly, if you wanted to manually change `createdAt`, this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

[Accodrding to the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/instance/#setkey-value-options), you can update an instance value by calling `instance.set(key, value, [options])`, so, in your case it should be:

```
console.log("BEFORE group.updatedAt " + group.updatedAt)
group.set('updatedAt', new Date())
console.log("CHANGED group.updatedAt " + group.updatedAt)
group.save().then((Group) => { /* the other part of your code*/ })
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but that also doesn't work.  In fact it wont update at all. Here is the log: `BEFORE group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
CHANGED group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED Group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
UPDATED group.updatedAt Fri Feb 17 2017 17:36:00 GMT-0800 (PST)`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update the updatedAt property on a model instance with the .changed() method. This only works if you set two property instances to changed = true

```
group.changed('updatedAt', true)
group.changed('exampleProperty', true)
await group.save({ silent: false })
```

Answer (score 1):

it's work

```js
sequelize.getQueryInterface().queryGenerator.updateQuery(
      'YOU_TABLE',
      { updated_at: sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') },
      { id: 1 },
      { returning: false },
)

sequelize.query(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that worked for me:

```js
await sequelize.query("UPDATE groups SET updatedAt = :date WHERE id = :id", {
  replacements: { date: new Date(2012, 7, 22, 2, 30, 0, 0), id: group.id },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few small changes to Alexander Zinchuk's code and it works for me:

```
await MyModel.update({ updatedAt: new Date() }, { where: { id: instance.id }})
```